# fill NSMutableArray with Accelerometervalues?

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, accelerometer

I have a question concerning NSMutableArray and it's alloc / init as a global thing.

What I want to do: stuff an NSMutableArray with acceleration values as long as a binary variable "permission" is set to true. I further want to stop the 'recording' in the array when I set permission to false and then get the array written to a file which I email off the phone. I coded all day (I may not be the most experienced coder" and fixed a lot of troubles like the permission setting, no file in the attachment (it was nil, tadaaa) using this forum but for this particular problem I cant seem to find a solution.

The point is, the attachment is nil and I can't think of a solution.

I do following at the beginning of the .m file:

```
    BOOL permission = NO; // key variable to enter recording / not recording state
    int i = 0; //used to determine place in dataArray
    NSMutableArray *dataArray; // axis values get dumped in here
```

To start recording,

```
    - (void)recordStart { //setting permission to yes
            permission = YES;
       }
```

this allows accelerometer:UIAccelerometer to fill the dataArray:

```
    (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

if (permission == YES) {

 //   NSLog(@"%f"@"%f"@"%f",acceleration.x,acceleration.y,acceleration.z);
    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f,       
    %f",acceleration.x,acceleration.y,acceleration.z];

    [dataArray addObject:valueString];

   // NSLog(@"%i",i);
    NSLog(@"Array Count: %d", [dataArray count]);


}
```

}

The NSLog always returns 0, so the array is empty and the stop method can't write the array to file, because it is nil:

```
    - (void)recordStop { //setting permission to no

NSLog(@"Array Count: %d", [dataArray count]);

[[dataArray componentsJoinedByString:@",\n"] writeToFile:[self setFileLocation] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

//code ommitted

Do i need to alloc the array somewhere else then globally? I can't do it in the accelerometer: function because it would just re-do that every single time it fires (i set a frequency of 100Hz)

Any suggestions?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is little but important. At the beginning, you did

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

to initialize your mutable array. The problem is, this only makes some space in the RAM for the object and not initialize it. So, you did not initialize the object, so it is nil. Here's the right way:

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Change that, compile and run it and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, I did try that before though and i get a compiler error: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Comment: Is it maybe possible to put Start / Stop on one button, thus using the array with one function (plus the accelerometer) and somehow retrieve the values in a different way? Java offers FileWriter, is there something similar available to Obj.C 2.0 ?

Comment: You said you defined the code 

BOOL permission = NO; // key variable to enter recording / not recording state
int i = 0; //used to determine place in dataArray
NSMutableArray *dataArray; // axis values get dumped in here '

at the beginning of the .m file. I think I know what you did wrong. Try moving that code into the  - (id)init method.

Comment: Uhm...  don't have that method? how would i call it?

I used Apples FlipView template, perhaps that helps?

Comment: Then you need to move it into viewDidLoad. It is the same as init (gets called at the beginning), but for view controllers. So, move it into there, and to make the variable available globally, in the .h file, declare the variable.

`@interface Example (UIViewController) {
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}`

There you should declare all your global variables.

In the .m file, remove the `NSMutableArray *` in front of the data array since we already declared it.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not. i declared the NSMutableArray *dataArray in the @interface MainviewController {} and dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the viewDidLoad.

The log still show up with 0 entries and the file is nil.